# How can I send a header with void response?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I'm working on a Spring project.

I'm currently doing this.

```java
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody final Some entity) {
    // persist the entity here
    final URI location = uriComponentsBuilder.path("{id}").buildAndExpand(entity.getId()).toUri();
    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
}
```

And I found the `@ResponseStatus`.

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void create(@RequestBody @NotNull final BaseType entity) {
    // persist the entity here
    // Location header to where?
}
```

Is there any way to send `Location` header with this way?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types

Comment: @JBNizet Will `ResponseEntity<?>` work anyway?

Comment: Why don't you test it an see by yourself?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm working on a library(common) module, sadly, no test environment yet.

Comment: Then setup one, and only when you have tested your code and have a concrete problem, come back here. We're not your testing environment. We won't test your code for you.

Comment: @JBNizet This is the second time that I became not ok by you. And I'm not thank for your recommendation.

Comment: Well, act like a programmer. Programmers don't ask "will this code compile?" or "will this code run?". They compile and run their code, and see by themselves. This is the minimum you can expect from a programmer.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks. wow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return response entity like below:

```
 return new ResponseEntity<>(location, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

or

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add(location);
return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
```

Comment: @JinKwon yes it will

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It returns your preferred header and status, without body.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT)
@RequestMapping("/teapot")
public HttpHeaders dummyMethod() {
    HttpHeaders h = new HttpHeaders();
    h.add("MyHeader", "MyValue");
    return h;
}
```